# What does <\1> mean in String#sub?

Tags: ruby, regex

I was reading [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-sub) and I did not understand it. I have two questions.

What is the difference `([aeiou])` and `[aeiou]`?

What does `<\1>` mean?

```
"hello".sub(/([aeiou])/, '<\1>')             #=> "h<e>llo"
```

Comment: “If `replacement` is a String it will be substituted for the matched text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form "`\d`", where *d* is a group number […]”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it [documented](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-sub):

> If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the **matched text**. It may contain **back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form `"\d"`**, where `d` is a group number, or `"\k<n>"`, where `n` is a group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must be preceded by an additional backslash. However, within replacement the special match variables, such as `&$`, will not refer to the current match.

[***Character Classes***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#label-Character+Classes)

> ***A character class is delimited with square brackets ([, ]) and lists characters that may appear at that point in the match.*** /[ab]/ means a or b, as opposed to /ab/ which means a followed by b.

Hope above definition made clear what `[aeiou]` is.

[***Capturing***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#label-Capturing)

> ***Parentheses can be used for capturing***. The text enclosed by the n<sup>th</sup> group of parentheses can be subsequently referred to with n. Within a pattern use the backreference \n; outside of the pattern use MatchData[n].

Hope above definition made clear what `([aeiou])` is.

`([aeiou])` - any characters inside the character class `[..]`,which will be found first from the string `"hello"`,is the value of `\1`(i.e.the first capture group). In this example value of `\1` is `e`,which will be replaced by `<e>` (as you defined `<\1>`). That's how `"h<e>llo"` has been generated from the string `hello` using `String#sub` method.

Answer (score 4):

The doc you post says

> It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the
>   form "\d", where d is a group number, or "\k", where n is a group
>   name.

So `\1` matches whatever was captured in the first `()` group, i.e. one of `[aeiou]` and then uses it in the replacement `<\1>`